# give input to a runnable jar file through a file

Tags: ant, jar

I have created a jar file using ant. I want the jar file to take input from a external file.
How can we achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking how to pass input parameters to a class in the jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

The [java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task has an **input** attribute that specifies the file that should be used as stdin.